# Convert array of char[] to bytes and then convert bytes to int and vise versa

Tags: c++

How to convert 4 characters “HERE” to a 4-byte integer that has the value 1163019592?

Here is what I tried:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "HERE";
    int n = s.length();

    int* number = new int[n + 1];
    char* cstr = new char[n+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cstr[i] = s[i];
        number[i] = cstr[i];
        cout << number[i];
    }
}
```

but instead of 1163019592, I get 72698269.

Comment: You should use `std::uint32_t` from <cstdint>, or any of the other 32-bit fixed width integer types if you want to be sure that it really is 4 bytes. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: The current version of the title is redundant, because you would read `char[]` in source code as "character array". I would suggest either "convert a string ..." or "Convert a character array ..." simple because code mark-up doesn't work well in titles.

Comment: If this is an assignment or student problem, it may be intended to exercise the bit-shift and bit-wise logic operators (some subset of `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `~`, `^`) as well as testing your understanding of how the variables that appear in your code are stored in memory.

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of naked uses of `new`. As-is, you have a memory leak because you aren't calling `delete[]` on `number` or `cstr`.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal `1163019592` is binary `01000101 01010010 01000101 01001000`, which is hex `0x45 0x52 0x45 0x48`.

`"HERE"` is bytes `0x48 0x45 0x52 0x45`.

Same bytes, different order.

If you want `"HERE"` to equate to `1163019592` without regard to endian, try this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string s = "HERE";
    size_t n = s.length();

    uint32_t number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        number = (number << 8) | static_cast<uint8_t>(s[n-i-1]);
    }

    cout << number;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/HbbX8g)